# Android activity is not started with any exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have created different activities with no problems so far, however, I have created now an activity called DetailsActivity that is not launched, with no exception, it just does not open (onCreate event is not getting called).

This is the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tdc"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_title"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.FormActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.GalleryActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.FormActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DetailsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.GalleryActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

This is the java class of the Activity:

```
package cl.virtualice.tdc.activities;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import cl.virtualice.tdc.R;

/**
 * Created by Jaime on 23-10-2015.
 */
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        Bitmap bitmap = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image");

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleTextView.setText(title);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

And finally, this is the code that tries to launch the activity:

```
                                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                                            ImageGalleryItem item = (ImageGalleryItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                            //Create intent
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                                            intent.putExtra("title", item.getTitle());
                                            intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());

                                            //Start details activity
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is onItemClick getting called?

Comment: Where are you calling onItemClick?

Comment: of course... I can debug it and the startActivity method is called, but nothing happens afterwards

Comment: onItemClick is executed when I click an item in a grid view. I have implemented an image grid view like this: http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android

Comment: what happens if you leave out the bitmap parts?

Comment: Check this line ```intent.putExtra("image", item.getImage());```, it could be an issue, since your image might not support parcelable

Comment: Have you looked in logcat for any errors or exceptions? Don't filter the logcat as you may miss something important/valuable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add those intents to a bundle and then unpack them in onCreate.

You put the Title as and extra and then write over it with the bitmap. Then in onCreate you try to get the title which was overwritten. I would be that it does not exist as an extra.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("TITLE", item.getTitle);
            b.putParcelable("BITMAP", item.getImage());

            intent.putExtras(b);
```